# Alert inside a jsp page before redirect

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to make an alert appear on a JSP page prior to redirecting to another page. The alert appears if I don't redirect. But when I redirect, the alert doesn't appear at all and immediately redirects. Is there any way around this?

Code:

```
if (rs.next()) {
                ResultSet getHashedPw = st.executeQuery("select password from user where username='" + userid + "' LIMIT 1");
                if(getHashedPw.next()){
                    String hashed = getHashedPw.getString(1);
                    if (BCrypt.checkpw(pwd, hashed)){
                        session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
                        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
                    }
                    else {

                        %>

                            <script>
                                alert("Error");
                            </script>

                        <%

                        response.sendRedirect("index.html");//works if I don't have this redirect. 
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                response.sendRedirect("index.html");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the redirection in javascript.

```
<script>
   alert("Error");
   window.location= "index.html";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I would also encourage using JSTL. It helps get over the issue of shoe-horning java source into your html which can become tricky and error prone as the app grows.

This this is especially useful for database driven webapps. The JSTL syntax does have a bit of a learning curve at first but it's worth it in the long run as you'll have a repo of tags at your disposal that you can reuse. see this [link](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jstl-credirect-core-tag/)